# Socket Exception only when connecting over IP but not localhost

Tags: c#, sockets, exception

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I only get this error when trying to connect via my public IP, if I use localhost it works fine.

My code:
(Note: Public IP/Local IP and Port have been censored here, but I'm using my public IPV4 Address and a specific port which has been Port forwarded as well as allowed through my computers firewall both inbound and outbound)
(Client):
`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace RemoteBG
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Socket client;
        IPEndPoint remote;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("PUBLICIP");
            IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, PORT);
            Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            client = sender;
            remote = remoteEP;
        }

        private void TextUpdate(String s)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(s + System.Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            try
            {
                // Connect to Remote EndPoint
                client.Connect(remote);

                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                    client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                // Encode the data string into a byte array.
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test<EOF>");

                // Send the data through the socket.
                int bytesSent = client.Send(msg);

                // Receive the response from the remote device.
                int bytesRec = client.Receive(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));

                // Release the socket.
                client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                client.Close();

            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                TextUpdate("Error connecting to Zang's PC. Error: " + se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", ex.ToString());
            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

`Server:`

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;


namespace RemoteBGServer
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int Main(String[] args)
        {
            StartServer();
            return 0;
        }

        public static void StartServer()
        {
            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("LOCALIP");
            IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, PORT);

            try
            {

                // Create a Socket that will use Tcp protocol
                Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                // A Socket must be associated with an endpoint using the Bind method
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                // Specify how many requests a Socket can listen before it gives Server busy response.
                // We will listen 10 requests at a time
                listener.Listen(10);

                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                Socket handler = listener.Accept();

                // Incoming data from the client.
                string data = null;
                byte[] bytes = null;

                while (true)
                {
                    bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                    data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                    if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Text received : {0}", data);

                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                handler.Send(msg);
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

`

Expected to see the test message "This is a test" instead got the exception.

This only occurs when using my public ip for IPHostEntry. Localhost works as expected.

Confirmed that the port is forwarded and firewall has exceptions for the port

Comment: Make sure that the server is not listening on 127.0.0.1 (localhost) only, but on the LAN interface. Also make sure that your router supports [NAT hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_hairpinning) if you try to reach your external IP address from inside your local network.

Comment: Try `IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IpAddress.Any, PORT);`

Comment: Ok I checked with a second person to see if it was the NAT Hairpinning issue, and I still get the error that the server doesnt respond in time.

Comment: Tried IpAddress.Any:

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10014): The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at RemoteBGServer.Program.StartServer() in C:\Users\Zang\source\repos\RemoteBGServer\RemoteBGServer\Program.cs:line 32